# Shifting characters in C++

Tags: c++, character

I tried to write a function to do simple shifting of characters (either to the left or right, depending on the shift parameter in the following function). Capital letters remain to be capital letters. Here is my approach:

```
char encodeCaesarCipherChar(char ch, int shift)
{
    char result;
    if (!isalpha(ch)) return ch;

    result = ch + shift;

    if (islower(ch) && result < 'a') {
        result += int('z') - 1;
        result -= int('a');
    } else if (islower(ch) && result > 'z') {
        result -= int('z');
        result += int('a') - 1;
    }  else if (isupper(ch) && result < 'A') {
        result += int('Z') - 1;
        result -= int('A');
    }  else if (isupper(ch) && result > 'Z') {
        result -= int('Z');
        result += int('A') - 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This function stops working properly when the input character is 's' and beyond. Could anyone please point out what's the problem to my approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `shift` you provided for test?

Comment: `int('z') - 1` the conversion from character literals to integer types is not required, because `char` is an integer type (not `int`, but an integer).

Comment: It works like charm for some values at least. Can you provide the calling code?

Comment: Re timrau, I used a value of 13 for the shift parameter.

Comment: Use `unsigned char` instead of char

Comment: Re Hulk, yes I changed that to type 'int' and it then works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

's' + 13 will overflow a signed `char`. Keep the result in an `int` and cast to `char` after adjusting the number and before returning.